# How to print an hexadecimal value stored in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, hex

```
int[] LETTERS = {0x69F99, 0xE9E9E, 0x78887}
System.out.println(LETTERS[1]);
```

When I do this, I get the integer value, but I need the 0x69F99 to be displayed in the console. Any ideas on how this can be done? P.S - This is for school purposes so I would like the most basic solution :b

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(LETTERS[1]));` ?

It should convert to a hexadecimal String representation for you and then print out as desired. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString(int)

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a quick reply Im pretty sure that your answer would be the solution, but we didn't learn that stuff in my class yet, so I can't use it :b

Comment: I don't think that is something you have to "specially" learn about before you can use it. You could have just checked the API and come across ways to convert to/from HEX.

Comment: Well, I think my teacher told us only to use the things we learned in class, but I think I will be using this for now and talk to him later, thanks for all of your help (:

Answer (score 0):

if you need to display as hex try this:

```
System.out.println(String.format("0x%x", LETTERS[1]));
```

Comment: I'm not into that matter in my class :(

Comment: @BrunoTavares not sure exactly what that means :) but above will print to the console `0xE9E9E` or this is not what you wanted?

Comment: my english is bad ehehe what I mean is that my teacher didn't talk about that in the class yet, but I will be talking to him if I can use this (: